# Storing array as value in associative array

Tags: perl

i have a problem where I need to have an array as a value in an associative array.

Go through the code below. Here I am trying to loop the files in a directory and it is more likely that more than 1 file can have the same `ctrno`. So, I would like to see what are all the files having the same `ctrno`. The code below gives error at "`$ctrno_hash[$ctrno] =  @arr;`" in the else condition. The same case would be for if condition as well.

Am I following the right approach or could it be done differently?

```
sub loop_through_files
{
    $file = "@_";
    open(INPFILE, "$file") or die $!;
    #print "$file:$ctrno\n";
    while (<INPFILE>)
    {
       $line .= $_;
    }
    if ($line =~ /$ctrno/ )
    {
       print "found\n";
       if ( exists $ctrno_hash[$ctrno])
       {
          local @arr = $ctrno_hash[$ctrno];
          push (@arr, $file);
          $ctrno_hash[$ctrno] =  @arr;
       }
       else
       {
          local @arr;
          push(@arr, $file);
          $ctrno_hash[$ctrno] =  @arr;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want something like

```
$ctrno_hash[$ctrno] =  \@arr;
```

This will turn the array `@arr` into a `array reference`.

You then refer to the previously *pushed* array reference with

```
@{$ctrno_hash[$ctrno]}
```

That is, if `$array_ref` is an array reference, the construct `@{ $array_ref }` returns the array to which the array reference points.

Now, the construct `$ctrno_hash[$ctrno]` is not really a hash, but an ordinary array. In order to truly make it a hash, you need the curly brackets instead of the square brackets:

```
@{$ctrno_hash{$ctrno} } = \@arr;
```

And similarly, you later refer to the array with

```
@{$ctrno_hash{$ctrno} }
```

Now, having said that, you can entirly forgo the `if ... exists` construct:

```
if ($line =~ /$ctrno/ )
{
   print "found\n";
   push @{$ctrno_hash{$ctrno}}, $file
}
```